# How to combine DI using IServiceProvider, a class with non-nullable fields and async initialization?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, dependency-injection

Imagine I have such a class in a WPF Solution:

```
public class TestClass
{
    private string _stringValue;
    private Database _database;
    
    public TestClass(Database database)
    {
        _database = database;
    }
    
    public async Task DoWork()
    {
        // do some async work involving _stringValue here
        // value of _stringValue comes from async database query
    }
}
```

The constructor parameters get resolved by `IServiceProvider` in `App.xaml.cs` via this code:

```
private IServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider()
{
    return new ServiceCollection()
        .AddSingleton<IDatabase, Database>()
        .AddTransient(s => new TestClass(s.GetRequiredService<IDatabase>()))
        .BuildServiceProvider();
}
```

What are best practices to initialize and work with fields in `TestClass`?

So far I'm doing this:

- Make `_stringValue` a nullable `string?`, initialize it as `string.Empty`, override that unused value and use it as `_stringValue!` all the time
- Create an `InitAsync()` Method, call it from an ugly `protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)` in `App.xaml.cs` when `IServiceProider` is built to query the database and hope my collegues don't forget it

Do I miss any better Method?

Comment: There's some boilerplate to write but I think the proper way to deal with this is defining a custom [Configuration Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#custom-configuration-provider) and injecting `IConfiguration` or using the Options pattern. You can configure your options to be loaded and validated at startup

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this small demo to put you in the right direction. The db call has to be synchronous, but it only happens the first time the Option is accessed (you could access it at startup or use the `DataAnnotations` extensions to eagerly load the values)

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

var services = new ServiceCollection();

services.AddTransient<A>();
services.Configure<AOptions>(x => x.Config = Db.LoadConfig());

var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

Console.WriteLine("Finished building ServiceProvider.");

var a1 = provider.GetRequiredService<A>();

a1.PrintConfig();

var a2 = provider.GetRequiredService<A>();

a2.PrintConfig();

var a3 = provider.GetRequiredService<A>();

a3.PrintConfig();


class A
{
    private readonly int _config;
    public A(IOptions<AOptions> options)
    {
        _config = options.Value.Config;
    }

    public void PrintConfig() => Console.WriteLine($"_config is {_config}");
}
class AOptions
{
    public int Config { get; set; }
}

class Db
{
    public static int LoadConfig()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Loaded config from database.");
        return 10;
    }
}
```